# lazy event publish subscribe in python

Tags: python, events, lazy-loading, publish-subscribe

I need an event messaging system in my google app engine application.

and i was referring to following python library.

http://pubsub.sourceforge.net/apidocs/concepts.html

my question is , is it must that the listener function i want to execute must be imported ( or exist otherwise) somewhere in to the execution path in order to run it on event ?

There are many lots of event, and I want to make it as lazy loaded as possible.

what could be the work around ?

is there any lazy event publish subscribe framework in python ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[tipfy](http://www.tipfy.org/) (an App-Engine specific micro framework) has lazy loading, but only for the specific "events" that are web requests your code is serving.  Other web frameworks have it too, but tipfy is small and simple enough to easily study and imitate its sources for the purpose.

So, if you can't find a richer event framework that's exactly to your taste because of the "lazy loading" issue, you could pick one which requires registration/subscription of callable objects, and allow *strings* naming functions to be registered as well, just as tipfy does.  The function thus named, of course, would be loaded just in time if an when needed to serve some event.

Let me exemplify with some simplified, hypothetical code.  Say that you have an event framework that includes something like:

```
import collections
servers = collections.defaultdict(list)

def register(eventname, callable):
    servers[eventname].append(callable)

def raise(eventname, *a, **k):
    for s in servers.get(eventname, ()):
        s(*a, **k)
```

The internals of any real-world event framework will be richer, of course, but something like this will be discernible at the lowest layers of it.

So, this requires the callable to be loaded at registration time... and yet, even without touching the internals of your framework, you can easily extend it.  Consider:

```
import sys

class LazyCall(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.f = None
    def __call__(self, *a, **k):
        if self.f is None:
            modname, funname = self.name.rsplit('.', 1)
            if modname not in sys.modules:
                __import__(modname)
            self.f = getattr(sys.modules[modname], funname)
        self.f(*a, **k)
```

You'll want better error handling &c, of course, but this is the gist of it: wrap the string naming the function (e.g. `'package.module.func'`) into a wrapper object that knows how to lazily load it.  Now, `register(LazyCall('package.module.func'))` will register, in the untouched framework, such a wrapper -- and lazy-load it on request.

This use case, btw, could be used as a reasonably good example of a Python idiom that some obstreperous fools claim, loudly and stridently, doesn't exist, or shouldn't exist, or something: an object dynamically changing its own class.  Use cases for this idiom are to "cut the middleman" for objects that exist in one of two states, with the transition from the first to the second being irreversible.  Here, the first state of a lazy caller is "I know the function's name but don't have the object", the second one is "I know the function object".  Since moving from the first to the second is irreversible, you can cut the small overhead of testing every time (or the indirection overhead of the `Strategy` design pattern), if you wish:

```
class _JustCallIt(object):
    def __call__(self, *a, **k):
        self.f(*a, **k)

class LazyCall(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.f = None
    def __call__(self, *a, **k):
        modname, funname = self.name.rsplit('.', 1)
        if modname not in sys.modules:
            __import__(modname)
        self.f = getattr(sys.modules[modname], funname)
        self.__class__ = _JustCallIt
        self.f(*a, **k)
```

The gain here is modest, as it basically just cuts one `if self.f is None:` check from each call; but it's a real gain, without real downsides except for causing the previously named obstreperous fools to flail into their typical angry and mindless frenzy (if you count *that* as a downside).

Anyway, the implementation choice is up to you, not to me -- or, lucky you, to them;-).

As is one design choice: whether to patch `register` itself to directly accept string arguments (and wrap them as needed), basically as `tipfy` does, or go for the explicit wrapping at the registration site, leaving `register` (or `subscribe` or however it's called) pristine.  I don't set much weight by the "explicit is better than implicit" mantra in this particular case, since something like

```
register(somevent, 'package.module.function')
```

is quite as explicit as

```
register(somevent, LazyCall('package.module.function'))
```

i.e., it **is** quite clear what's going on, and it's arguably cleaner / more readable.

Nevertheless, it *is* really nice that the explicit wrapping approach leaves the underlying framework untouched: wherever you could pass a function, you can now pass the *name* of that function (as a string naming packages, module, and the function itself), seamlessly.  So, were I retrofitting existing frameworks, I'd go for the explicit approach.

Finally, if you want to register callables that are not functions but (for example) instances of certain classes, or bound methods of such instances, you can enrich `LazyCall` into variants such as `LazyInstantiateAndCall` &c for the purpose.  The architecture becomes a tad more complex, of course (since you want ways to instantiate new objects *and* ways to identify already existing ones, for example), but by delegating that work to a well designed system of factories, it shouldn't be *too* bad.  However, I'm not getting any deeper in such refinements, since this answer is already rather long, and anyway, in many cases, the simple "name a function" approach should suffice!-)

Comment: thanks. i got it. but how to listen anywhere ? ( i.e. without passing through that function in execution ? )

Comment: @lamgopal, **HUH**?  I don't understand your question at all.  I showed how to use **ANY** framework that lets you register functions, without loading the function _until_ it's needed to serve an event, i.e., it gets called, and _then_ of course it's loaded **and** executed -- how could you possibly want to avoid **that**?!  The "listening" is going to be done in the framework -- your serving function executes only when it must execute in response to an event -- what **other** specs did you completely forget in your original Q?  I can't imagine any that are sensible... pls clarify!

Comment: sorry to not clear it up. I did not wanted to avoid listening or execution. I wanted to avoid "registration" of listeners, as there are a lot many in my case, and distributed all over the code.e.g. there is a listener register in x module which is not imported while executing main from y module. if some function in y module create an invent, will a listener function in x module executed ? NO, because interpreter did not reach there .  so how do I make sure listener in x executed without importing module x beforehand to register it in first place ?,i think it is not possible( to next comment)

Comment: so only solution i have is to register all the listener in one file and importing it first in main function. anyway, thanks for your answer, it was informative.

Comment: @iamgopai, there has to be _some_ where the knowledge of what listener exists and what events they care about.  You could have that in a "configuration file" (just pairs of string event name / listener name, or something more sophisticated like a listener name followed by 1+ event names, etc, etc) which is read by a routine that does all registrations.  If that knowledge is spread all over N modules, there is no way to get at it without importing N modules, of course;-).  I think a configuration file is a reasonable architectural choice for your use case.